# PHP DateTime object, unexpected results

Tags: php, arrays, datetime

I have two DateTime objects, basically a To & From value. I need to iterate over this object and output this to a form. For some bizarre reason it's always one date value short.

```
$this->custom_from_date = new DateTime();
$this->custom_to_date = new DateTime();
//add six days in the future
$this->custom_to_date ->modify("+6 day");
//subtract 1 day from the past
$this->custom_from_date->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
//setup date interval between two dates
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$this->setToDate($this->custom_to_date->format('Ymd'));
$this->setFromDate($this->custom_from_date->format('Ymd'));
//create the date range object out of the interval
$daterange = new DatePeriod($this->custom_from_date, $interval, $this->custom_to_date);
```

then I try to iterate over the date range like so:

```
foreach ($daterange as $date): ?>
    <th>
    <?= $date->format('m/d') ?><br>  O:  R:  D:
    </th>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

it outputs:

```
O: R: D:    11/13
O: R: D:    11/14
O: R: D:    11/15
O: R: D:    11/16
O: R: D:    11/17
O: R: D:    11/18
O: R: D:    11/19
```

it returns a 7 index array, not 8 as I would expect (11/20 being the last to be output). Why would that be?

I understand I could just add one more day to the modify method, however I need specific dates for various sql queries. They all share the same custom date class, my results do not match my daterange object.

Comment: See this comment: http://php.net/manual/en/dateperiod.construct.php#100730

Comment: @Koen. That's so bizarre, I don't understand why it would exclude the last element. Furthermore, I don't really know how to remedy this.

Comment: See the next comment on the same page: http://php.net/manual/en/dateperiod.construct.php#109661